# How to make tablayout fixed below action bar?

Tags: android

I have the following layout where I have an image slider above a tablayout:

[image: Slider above tablayout]

But I want to have it fixed to top as shown in the following image:

[image: Slider fixed to top]

This is my current code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:scrollbars="none"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <com.daimajia.slider.library.SliderLayout
        android:id="@+id/slider"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        />

    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/white"
        app:tabGravity="fill"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        app:tabIndicatorColor="#000"
        app:tabMode="fixed"
        app:tabSelectedTextColor="@color/colorTextPrimary"
        app:tabTextColor="@color/colorTextDisable">

        <android.support.design.widget.TabItem
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="All"/>

        <android.support.design.widget.TabItem
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Casual"/>

        <android.support.design.widget.TabItem
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="WoMen"/>

        <android.support.design.widget.TabItem
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="New Jeans"/>

    </android.support.design.widget.TabLayout>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="800dp"/>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/viewpager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/tablayout"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" >
    </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>
</LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> If you want to move your `TabLayout` up then you need to either make
>   the        `visibilty` of `SliderLayout` `gone` or set the height of
>   `SliderLayout` to `0dp`.

Use this below code it will fulfil your requirement as you want in second picture.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:scrollbars="none"
    android:id="@+id/scrollView"
>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <com.daimajia.slider.library.SliderLayout
            android:id="@+id/slider"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="200dp" //set this value to 0dp or set the visibilty GONE HERE(if you just want to hide visibilty)
            />

        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            app:tabGravity="fill"
            app:tabIndicatorColor="#000"
            app:tabMode="fixed">

            <android.support.design.widget.TabItem
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="All" />

            <android.support.design.widget.TabItem
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Casual" />


            <android.support.design.widget.TabItem
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="WoMen" />

            <android.support.design.widget.TabItem
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="New Jeans" />

        </android.support.design.widget.TabLayout>

        <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="800dp" />

        <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
            android:id="@+id/viewpager"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/tablayout"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"></android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>
    </LinearLayout>


</ScrollView>
```

and then do this Programatically

```
  scrollView.getViewTreeObserver().addOnScrollChangedListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnScrollChangedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onScrollChanged() {
                if (scrollView != null) {
                    if (scrollView.getChildAt(0).getBottom() <= (scrollView.getHeight() + scrollView.getScrollY())) {
                        slider.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    }
                    else {
                        slider.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    }
                }
            }
        });
```

Comment: but on scroll i want to hide slider

Comment: In on create activity

Comment: i do not understand where to add this code block .... Please can you help

Comment: inside your java activity class , add this above code in onResume method like this ------------------------------------------

 @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        ScrollView scrollView = findViewById(R.id.scrollView);
        SliderLayout slider = findViewById(R.id.slider);
        // ADD THAT ABOVE CODE HERE

    }

Comment: when i scroll up it will be fixed at top and again when i scroll down slider layout may be again visible as first image of mine

Comment: it helps me sir

Comment: when i scroll up it will be fixed at top and again when i scroll down slider layout may be again visible as first image of mine..........this is my last question